# Saving Database issue

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

So basically, I believe I am using the correct code yet the database will still not update. It will work for the current session, however, when I stop and restart the program, it appears that the data has not been updated in the database.

The really interesting part is that I am using the same method to update the database elsewhere, which when used and session restarted, the database has been updated.

p.s. I also have the same adapters and binding sources set up etc on both forms
I am so confused, help pls

Code that I believe is correct but is not working: (updating on another form so I have one place where all forms update hence FRMMain. etc)

```
Private Sub btnConfirm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConfirm.Click
    Dim CurrentPoints As Integer
    Dim UpdatedPoints As Integer

    CurrentPoints = FRMMain.MyDBDataSet.Tables("TBLPupil").Rows(looopcount)(15)
    UpdatedPoints = CurrentPoints + stfPoints
    FRMMain.MyDBDataSet.Tables("TBLPupil").Rows(looopcount)(15) = UpdatedPoints

    FRMMain.TBLPupilTableAdapter.Update(MyDBDataSet.TBLPupil)
    FRMMain.TBLPupilTableAdapter.Fill(MyDBDataSet.TBLPupil)

End Sub
```

Code that I am using in another form that that DOES work:

```
    Private Sub BtnYes_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnYes.Click
    Dim Points As Integer = FRMPupil.Pointss
    Dim Cost As Integer = FRMPupil.RewardCost
    Points = Points - Cost
    FRMPupil.LePoints = Points

    MyDBDataSet.Tables("TBLPupil").Rows(FRMLogin.DBLocation)(15) = Points
    FRMMain.TBLPupilTableAdapter.Update(MyDBDataSet.TBLPupil)
    FRMMain.TBLPupilTableAdapter.Fill(MyDBDataSet.TBLPupil)

    Me.Hide()

End Sub
```

Comment: What value is returned when you call `Update`? There are only three possibilities: it returns zero, it returns a non-zero value or it doesn't return and throws an exception.

Comment: By the way, if you have a typed `DataSet` then use it.  This is how you use an untyped `DataSet`: `FRMMain.MyDBDataSet.Tables("TBLPupil").Rows(looopcount)(15) = UpdatedPoints`. Using a typed `DataSet` should look like this: `FRMMain.MyDBDataSet.TBLPupil(looopcount).Points = UpdatedPoints`. I've made a guess at the column name being `Points` but you can change that to whatever is appropriate. Some of the reasons to use a typed `DataSet` are no magic strings, Intellisense and strict typing. If you're not going to use them then don;t use a typed `DataSet` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> My code is correct but is not working.

**No**, if it is not working, then it is not correct!

There are different things you can do: DRY, [**D**ont **R**epeat **Y**ourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). You are repeating the code for updating points at several places in your code. This is error prone. Write it once and re-use it, e.g. by applying the the [Repository Pattern](https://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/). It makes it easier to detect errors and correct them. It allows you to re-use code that has already been tested in other scenarios (on another form).

Debug, debug, debug. Place breakpoints in the not working methods and see what happens. Do all the variables have the expected values? E.g., does `looopcount` have the same value as `FRMLogin.DBLocation`? There must be a difference somewhere. See: [Navigating through Code with the Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or the more recent article [Debug your Hello World application with Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/debugging-with-visual-studio?tabs=csharp).